# How do I make existing functions in math and numpy module support user-defined objects?

Tags: python, oop, numpy, math, magic-methods

I defined a class that I'd like basic operations such as `+`, `-`, and even more advanced math operations such as `sin` to support. That is, I need to define some new rules for these basic operators and math functions.

I could deal with basic operators using Python's magic methods as below,

```
class NewObj():

    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass

    def __add__(self, other):
        pass

    def __mul__(self, other):
        pass

    # Use magic methods to define other basic operators below...
```

And I could also redefine basic functions in the same .py file where class `NewObj` is defined, such as

```
def sin(x):
    pass
```

And name this file as, say, myoperator.py. Then I could import this module and apply new operations on `NewObj` objects.

---

But I also want existing functions in `numpy` and `math` to support my `NewObj` objects so that `math.sin()` and `numpy.sin()` also support my newly defined `NewObj` objects. How can I achieve this?

Another question is: is it possible to encapsulate functions inside my `NewObj` class just like magic methods so that all the stuff are written inside a class data structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `math` module explicitly documents that functions like `math.sin` always return floats. If you want `math.sin(your_object)` to return a `NewObj` instance instead of a `float`, **don't do that**. It'll confuse the hell out of everyone if you even make it work, and it'll cause initialization order bugs and other headaches. (There's a reason NumPy has its own `numpy.sin` instead of trying to make `math.sin` support NumPy arrays.)

If you're okay with `math.sin(your_object)` returning a float, then implement a `__float__` method to convert your objects to floats:

```
class NewObj(object):
    ...
    def __float__(self):
        return whatever
```

`math.sin` will convert your object to a float, compute the sine of the float, and return the sine as a float.

---

For NumPy, just implement a `sin` method:

```
class NewObj(object):
    ...
    def sin(self):
        return whatever
```

`numpy.sin` will delegate to your `sin` method. You can have it return a `NewObj`; there's no need to cast to float or anything. Most similar NumPy functions will delegate to methods similarly. That said, trying to use custom objects inside NumPy arrays defeats most of the efficiency benefits of NumPy, so you might want to rethink your design if you want to do that.

Comment: Re the `numpy` bit of your answer. This looks very useful. How does it relate to the current `__array_priority__` and friends? And the future `__numpy_ufunc__` for that matter? Could you provide a pointer? Thanks!

Comment: @PaulPanzer: I don't think `__array_priority__` would come up in this situation. As for `__numpy_ufunc__`, I don't know how `__numpy_ufunc__` will interact with this.

Answer (score 2):

You can redefine the `math` module's `sin`.

```
import math

class NewObj:
    pass

old_sin = math.sin

def new_sin(number):
    return 42.0 if isinstance(number, NewObj) else old_sin(number)

math.sin = new_sin
```

Presumably you replace `42.0` with an even more useful definition.

Comment: Works for me.  If I write `import math; import myoperator as mo; print(math.sin(mo.NewObj()))` in a script and run it, it prints `42.0`.  I'm using CPython 3.6.0.

Comment: You still have to `import math` explicitly in your script in order to be able to call `math.sin`, but yeah, `import myoperator` redefines the behavior of `math.sin`.  The reason I don't consider this bad is that the redefinition of `math.sin` doesn't change how it acts on data types on which it was already defined.  It only adds a new type to which it can be applied, so the change shouldn't break any other code.

Comment: This is going to cause all kinds of initialization order issues and other headaches. If someone does `from math import sin` before your code runs, they'll have the old `math.sin`, and you'll have `math.sin` mysteriously supporting your objects in some places and not in others. If they read the docs and source code for `math.sin`, it'll be utterly baffling how it's handling your objects. I'd strongly recommend not doing this.

Comment: @user2357112 If someone does `from math import sin`, he probably can't call `math.sin` if he hasn't imported `math`. If one sticks on using `math.sin` rather than `sin`, will this solve the initialization problem you mentioned?

Comment: @Nicholas: Qualified references to `math.sin` won't suffer from the initialization order issue, unless you somehow let references to your objects escape and have `math.sin` called on them between the class definition and the replacement of `math.sin`.

Comment: @user2357112 Then why qualified references `math.sin` would mysteriously support one's objects in some places and not in others?

Comment: @Nicholas: *Un*qualified references would mysteriously not support your objects, depending on initialization order.

Answer (score 1):

There will in the hopefully not so far future be a `__numpy_ufunc__` special attribute (name subject to [change](http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/numpy-ufunc-td43718.html)). Here's the relevant bit from the numpy docs' [dev version](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.classes.html)

> `class.__numpy_ufunc__(ufunc, method, i, inputs, **kwargs)`
>
> New in version 1.11.
>
> Any class (**ndarray subclass or not**) can define this method to override behavior of NumPy’s ufuncs.

[emphasis mine]

Comment: @MadPhysicist "doesn't answer the question at all"? If you read the Q I think you will find the OP is asking quite specifically for `math` and `numpy` functions. So this covers 50%. And there is the magic method tag. Numpy functions that are not `ufuncs` are hardly relevant here. Besides, why this negative attitude?

Comment: If it involves enough pretty formatting I prefer to see information in an `answer` than a comment.  But I'm not sure this is helpful in the OP case.  It looks like it will be more useful when a ndarray subclass needs special behavior for a `ufunc`.  Defining `ufunc` is probably beyond the OP's needs.

Comment: @hpaulj well, it does say "Any class (ndarray subclass or not)" But I admit I don't really understand how it all fits together.

Comment: Reading more on `__numpy_ufunc` I see that a big motivator is better integration of `scipy.sparse` matrices.  In fact such a method is defined in my current version of that package. It takes a dozen of the `ufuncs` and defines how they should delegate to existing sparse methods.

Comment: I apologize for the negative way I responded to your post. I was having a long day and it was unfair of me to take it out on you. However, I think the idea I expressed so badly is valid. You refer to a currently non-existent feature, and I am not sure that the narrative you have actually shows OP how to use this feature to solve his immediate problem. Again, apologies for my rudeness.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for coming back on that. It is appreciated. Apologies accepted, of course. I still do genuinely think it is a valid answer. A detail, certainly, but if I were researching this question and I didn't already know I certainly would want to know about this. I'm not sure what exactly official SO policies are. My rule of thumb is if it is useful for the OP or someone likely to find the question it should be there.

Comment: I have removed my downvote because you are right, this is valuable information for someone that already knows how to use it. I made a small edit to make that possible. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @MadPhysicist And I was wondering and wondering what could possibly be wrong with 'my emphasis'. ;-)